# Is this a valid construction?

Tags: category-theory

I have recently started learning basic category theory, and this thought crossed my mind.

**The Category of Mathematical Propositions**

**The Objects:**
    Objects in this category, henceforth referred to as $\text{Prop}$, are pairs $(X,p)$. $X$ and $p$ are both sets. $X$ being
some generic set and $p$ being a set of properties that apply to $X$. More concretely,

$$p = \lbrace x : x \text{ is a mathematical property}\rbrace$$

with those additional properties. That is, for any $x,x'$ that are elements of $p$, $x$ must not contradict $x'$ and vice versa. $p$
must also be 'reduced', by which we mean that if for any subset $u$ of $p$, the elements of $u$ do no imply any other element of
$p$ to be true. We will call such pairs 'mathematical propositions'.

**The Morphisms:**
    Intuitively, morphisms in $\text{Prop}$ are implications. That is $\text{Mor}(X,Y)$ is the set of ways that $X$ implies $Y$. If we return
to the more formal definition of mathematical propositions, we can define these morphisms in the following manner. Take
two pairs $(X,p)$ and $(Y,q)$. The first thing that becomes apparent is that we need $Y$ to be a subset of $X$, so in fact, the only thing
that this morphism does is map one set of propositions to another. Let

$$p = \lbrace a_1, a_2, a_3, \dotsc, a_n\rbrace\text{ and } q = \lbrace b_1, b_2, b3, \dotsc, b_m\rbrace.$$

We can then define a function between these two sets that 'rearranges' $p$ to become $q$. It does this by taking a subset of $p$
and some $b_w$ that these properties imply. For such a morphism to exist, it must be surjective, as if it were not it would
not tell us that $X$ implies $Y$, because their $X$'s properties would not imply $Y$'s.

Is this a valid construction, and if so, is it of any use?

Comment: Maybe if you define "is a mathematical property" this question will be answerable.

Comment: I left it specifically generic to make it as general as possible, essentially it is any property that a set can have, or any property that these properties can have. Is that specific enough?

Comment: No. "Property" isn't a formally defined concept. It *can* be formalized in various ways. For the most obvious logical formulation, it simply doesn't make any sense to talk about "properties" being elements of sets. You could talk about sets of formulas of some formal language, how these would relate to $X$ is unclear. Typically the way "properties" are internalized into set theory is as subsets. With this, $p$ would just be the set of subsets of $X$. Presumably you want subsets of that set. Maybe you should flesh out a concrete realization before trying to "make it as general as possible".

Comment: On the other hand, there are categories that I think capture the idea you are trying to articulate. For example, entailment is usually a reflexive, transitive relation, so you can make a preorder category whose objects are formulas (in a formal language) and for which there is an arrow between formulas if the source entails the target. This idea can be [vastly expanded](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic) forming the fields of categorical logic and type theory, and categorical semantics.